# A $C^1$ function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ whose critical value has a non-zero measure.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Does there exist a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\xrightarrow{C^1}\mathbb{R}$ such that the critical value has a non-zero measure?

It is not satisfying the condition of [Sard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem), as in the Sard's theorem, we need at least $C^2$ regularity. So I believe such a function exists, but unable to construct.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258141/a-counterexample-for-sards-theorem-in-c1-regularity/330496#330496

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whitney constructed such examples, and it seems that [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404404.pdf) is inspired by his work (I am unable to find Whitney's article "A function not constant on a connected set of critical points" free of access).

Comment: Thanks, for this. It is really helpful. The references in the above article are very useful.